# parse email content from mbox in python

Tags: python, email

Here is the code that I am running to parse the contents of mbox in my home directory.

```
import sys
import mailbox

def gen_summary(filename):
    mbox = mailbox.mbox(filename)
    for message in mbox:
       subj = message['subject']
       sender = message['from'] 
       content = message.get_payload()
       print subj,sender
       print(content)
```

The subject and sender are printed fine but the content is printed as an instance like below :

```
[<email.message.Message instance at 0x7f831f3df758>, <email.message.Message instance at 0x7f831f3e43f8>]
```

The actual content was the text below :

```
Xyz.abc.com
Lmn.pqr.com
Def.ghi.com
```

My goal is to write a script to accept all incoming emails for a user and process the contents and send the results back to the sender. Let me know if there are better ways to do that.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message) says that `message.get_payload()` returns a `list` of `message` objects, which is what you're seeing. Can you try changing the last line to something like `for c in content: print c`?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Outlook, where a Message is instance of a MailItem having some methods and properties attached to it, so you can access it like `Msg.Subject`,  `Msg.Body`, `Msg.To` etc.

For the `Mailbox` there is a following [mbox python tutorial](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2007/06/28/processing-mailbox-files-with-mailboxpy.html?page=1)  that is exactly answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

The message payload was multipart.
I checked for len(message.get_payload()) which shows "2"
then I printed both the parts seperately.

And I got the content out of message.get_payload()[0].get_payload().
Result was as expected :

```
Xyz.abc.com
Lmn.pqr.com
Def.ghi.com
```